# Showing that the square root is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've shown the existence of unique square roots of all positive rational numbers, so now I want to prove that the square root is monotone:

$0<a<b$ if and only if $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well we have:

$$b-a>0\Leftrightarrow\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}=\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}>0. $$

Comment: this is really simple and clean! nicely done!

Comment: what about the other direction? assuming that $\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} > 0$

Comment: Multiply by $\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}$ which must be positive since $a,b>0$.

Answer (score 9):

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be $f(x)=\sqrt x$. Then $\displaystyle f^\prime(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}>0$ so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: wow, wouldn't have thought to use the derivative, thanks.

Comment: does this give me an if and only if relation though?

Comment: yes. $f(x)$ is strictly increasing means $f(x)<f(y)$ if and only if $x<y$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that if $p, q, r, s$ are positive and $p < q, r < s$ then $pr < qs$. Let $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$ using $p = r = \sqrt{a}, q = s = \sqrt{b}$ we get $a < b$.

Let $a < b$. Clearly we can't have $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b}$ as this will mean $a = b$ (by squaring). Also we can't have $\sqrt{a} > \sqrt{b}$ as by previous part it would mean $a > b$. Hence we must have $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0\leq a\leq b$ and $\sqrt b <\sqrt a.$ Then there is an $ε>0$ such that $\sqrt a=\sqrt b + ε.$ So we have $a-b=(\sqrt a)^2-(\sqrt b)^2=(\sqrt b + ε)^2-(\sqrt b)^2=2ε\sqrt b+ε^2=ε(2\sqrt b+ε)=ε(\sqrt b+\sqrt a)>0$, which contradicts to our assumption. Thus $\sqrt a \leq\sqrt b.$