# Compare $b=10.6^{-1}$ and $c=\sqrt{(-1.67)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which of the numbers is the smallest?
$$a=\sqrt{3}\\b=10.6^{-1}\\c=\sqrt{(-1.67)^2}\\d=6.3^{-1}$$

So we have $$b=10.\dfrac{1}{6}=\dfrac{5}{3}=\sqrt{\dfrac{25}{9}}=\sqrt{2\frac{7}{9}}=\sqrt{2.(7)}\\c=\sqrt{1.67^2}=\sqrt{2.7889}\\d=6.\dfrac{1}{3}=2=\sqrt{4}$$

So we have to compare $b$ and $c$. How can we do that?

Comment: Note that $10.6^{-1}$ is $\frac{1}{10.6}$.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate it, just use that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. Also, you probably meant $10 \cdot 6^{-1}$ for multiplication, that's `\cdot` in mathjax.

Comment: @dxiv, what do you mean "don't overcomplicate it"? If we used the suggested property, we are left with $\sqrt{3}$, $1\frac{2}{3}$ and $1.67$. How am I supposed to compare these numbers?

Comment: @Medi I believe they mean you can use that $2.(7) < 2.78$

Comment: @Medi $a$ and $d$ are both larger than $b$, so you (should) have excluded those already. What's left is to compare $b$ and $c$. The way you stated the problem, you just have to find the smallest number, and that doesn't require you to sort all four numbers in order.

Comment: Are those dot's decimal points or multiplications signs?

Comment: " we are left with 3–√, 123 and 1.67. How am I supposed to compare these numbers? "  Seriously?  $1\frac 23 = 1.66666666..... < 1.67$ and as you pointed out $1.67^2 = 2.7889$ and $2.7889 < 3$.  But again... are the dots multiplication signs or decimal points.

Comment: Note $\frac 79 = 0.777777777.....$  so you are asking how to compare $\sqrt{2.77777...}$ with $\sqrt{2.7889}$.  But you are *way* over complicating it as per dxiv comment.  $\frac 53 = 1.666666..... < 1.67 < 2$   And if we square and compare to $3$ we get $\frac {25}9 < 2.789 < 3 < 4$ so $\frac 53 < 1.67 < \sqrt 3 < 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{3}=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{3}= \frac{\sqrt{27}}{3}$$

$$\frac{10}{6} = \frac{5}{3}$$

$$\sqrt{(-1.67)^2} = |-1.67|=1.67 > \frac{5}{3}$$

Since $5<(1.67 \times 3)<\sqrt{27}<6$,

$$\frac{10}{6}<\sqrt{(-1.67)^2}<\sqrt{3}<\frac{6}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

We'll use that

[$$0<x<y \iff \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{y} \tag{1}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/670480/695196)

Notice that $c =\sqrt{(-1.67)^2} = \lvert -1.67 \rvert = 1.67$. If $b = \frac{10}{6} = \frac{5}{3}$ and $d = \frac{6}{3}$ (as you've used in your steps), then you get the following:
$$
0<25<\underbrace{25.1001}_{\color{purple}{(5.01)^2}} <27 <36 \overset{(1)}{\implies} 5 <5.01<3\sqrt{3}<6 \implies \underbrace{\frac{5}{3}}_{\color{blue}{b}} <\underbrace{1.67}_{\color{blue}{c}}<\underbrace{\sqrt{3}}_{\color{blue}{a}}<\underbrace{\frac{6}{3}}_{\color{blue}{d}}
$$
where on the last step we multiplied everything by $\frac{1}{3}>0$, which doesn't change the order of inequality. **So $b$ is the smallest number.**

---

Notice that
$$
0<y<x \implies x^{-1} < y^{-1} \tag{2}
$$
since multiplying $0<y<x$ by $x^{-1}y^{-1}>0$ gives the desired result.

If $b = \frac{1}{10.6}$ and $d = \frac{1}{6.3}$ we do the following. Note that both $a,c>1$ since $c =1.67 >1$ and that $3>1 \overset{(1)}{\implies}  a=\sqrt{3}>\sqrt{1}=1$.

Lastly, since $0<1<6.3<10.6$, by $(2)$ taking the reciprocals will invert the inequalities. So
$$
\underbrace{10.6^{-1} }_{\color{blue}{b}}<  \underbrace{6.3^{-1} }_{\color{blue}{d}}  < 1 < a,c
$$
so $b$ is again the smallest number on the list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the dots in $b,d$ are multiplication signs and the the dot in $c$ is a decimal point.

b) $10\cdot 6^{-1} = \frac {10}{6} = \frac 53 = 1\frac 23$.  In decimals this is $1.66666......$

c) $\sqrt{(-1.67)^2} = 1.67$.

d) $6\cdot 3^{-1} = \frac 63 = 2$.

So by comparing decimals $d > c > b$.

To compare to $\sqrt 3$ we square each term and compare to $3$.

$(1\frac 23)^2 = (\frac 53)^2 = \frac {25}9 = 2\frac 79 < 3$. SO $1\frac 23 < \sqrt 3$.

$2^2 = 4 > 3$ so $2 > \sqrt 3$.

So $d > a > b$.  So we just need to compare $a$ to $c$.

$1.67$ is *very* close to $1\frac 23$ so $1.67^2$ will be very close to $(1\frac 23)^2 = 2\frac 79$ so it will *probably* be smaller than $3$.  But $1.67^2$ will be larger than $2\frac 79$ but will it be $\frac 29$ or more larger? That's almost surely impossible.  But lets make sure.

$1.67 - 1.666666...... = 0.003333333.... = 0.001\times \frac 13 = \frac 1{3000}$.

So $1.67 = 1\frac 23 + \frac 1{3000}$ so

$1.67^2 = (1\frac 23)^2 + 2\frac 1{3000} (1\frac 23) + \frac 1{3000^2}$

$2\frac 79 + \frac {10}{9000} + \frac 1{9000000}=$

$2 \frac 79 + \frac 1{900} + \frac 1{9000000} < $

$2\frac 79 + \frac 19 + \frac 19=$

$2\frac 79 + \frac 29 = 3$.

So $1.67 < \sqrt 3$ so

$d > a > b > c$.

Comment: I believe you have a typo on the last inequality, $b$ and $c$ should be interchanged. You previously argued that $d > c > b$.